# Why doesn't Console.WriteLine output anything to the NuGet Package Manager window?

Tags: powershell

Can anyone tell me why the following code doesn't show "blablabla" to the PS screen?  All I see is the random number that is returned from the function.

```
# Create a function that loads our managed code into powershell
function InitType 
{ 
    [string]$SourceCode =  @"

    using System;

    namespace TestApp 
    {       

        // This class houses the public methods that we'll use from powershell

        public static class TestMethods
        {
            public static int GetRandom()
            {
                var id = new Random().Next();
                Console.WriteLine("bla bla bla");
                return id; 
            }
        }
    }
"@

    # use the powershell 2.0 add-type cmdlet to compile the source and make it available to our powershell session 
    add-type -TypeDefinition $SourceCode
}

# Load our C# code 
InitType

# Call our method 
[TestApp.TestMethods]::GetRandomAndOutputMessage
```

()

Comment: It does on my system, if I call [TestApp.TestMethods]::GetRandom() and use an int instead of var. Please check you've posted the right code.

Comment: On powershell v3.0 your code works! Calling `[TestApp.TestMethods]::GetRandom()`

Comment: Maybe I' missing something, but TestMethods defines GetRandom() and not GetRandomAndOutputMessage()

Comment: Down-voted?  Yikes.  Could my problem be that I am executing the script from the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio?  I will try from the typical PS console and see what happens.

Comment: Did you ever compare with typical PS Console? I'm interested in the results.

Answer (score 3):

Nuget Package Manager is not *the* PowerShell console.  Console.WriteLine write to the console of a console "application".  Visual Studio is not a console application.  The window that runs NPM is hosting the PowerShell engine and implementing the PSHost interfaces to allow the engine to output information to the window.  Console.WriteLine will not work in that scenario.